# Field (?) cannot be parsed node cron

Tags: node.js, cron

I am setting up cron-manager in my node application. I am sending '5 0/0 * 1/1 * ? *' from UI which is created using cron-editor.This expression means in every 5 second.
I am not able to resolve the error. Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Try '*/5 * * * * *'

Comment: @KarthickSrinivasan yup this is working fine.... but how can i achieve or convert to this. As my cron editor send me this value

Comment: can you tell me which module should i use on UI side to create this.... i am stucked

Comment: If you are using angular as front end then this may help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cron-editor

Comment: @KarthickSrinivasan By using this module, cron manager accepts the job but it is not running on the specific time. When i create expression for every 1 minute and output is : 0/1 * 1/1 * *. Is it right?? as i have tested but job is not working as expected.